# Error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the error below when I destroy and create datatable

```
RadioButton rdb2 = new RadioButton();
RadioButton rdb3 = new RadioButton();
rdb1 = (RadioButton)DataList1.Items[item.Id].FindControl("One");
rdb2 = (RadioButton)DataList1.Items[item.Id].FindControl("Three");
rdb3 = (RadioButton)DataList1.Items[item.Id].FindControl("Seven");
```

What I am doing is based on the user selection I am calling the data from database and put it into a new data table which I use as DataScouce for my DataList.

Please help me how to solve this error. I have seen the [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/836874) also for solution but it didn't help.

Comment: What is `item.Id` (it's value)?

Comment: How many `Item` your `DataList1` has?

Comment: Where do you have this code in context to the destroying and creation of datatable ?

Comment: DataList1 has dynamic items, it depends on the no. of items present in my db.

Comment: @V4Vendetta I have not written any code for destroy and creation of data table. Its like overwriting. If datatable has got items in it and when i click on another item then it will come to the same page calling the db with new query to fill the data table again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to reference an item in `DataList.Items` that does exist at position `Item.Id`.

Ensure that `DataList.Items` contains elements and that `Item.Id` has a valid value (And not higher than the total number of elements in `DataList.Items`)

Assuming `item.Id` is a valid integer, you could check to see if `item.Id` is smaller than the collection:

```
RadioButton rdb2 = new RadioButton();

if (item.Id <= DataList.Items.Count()) {
  rdb2 = (RadioButton)DataList1.Items[item.Id].FindControl("Three");
}
```

Comment: Microsoft has an article on this at this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/836874 but without any solution..

Comment: @user1126060 - it's not a bug with ADO.NET/MS.  You are trying to access an element in your collection that is out of range.  I.e. if I have an array with 3 items (0, 1, 2) called Darren.  I can get the items by doing.  Darren[0], Darren[1], Darren[2].  If I however do Darren[100] it will throw an exception (Because my array has 3 elements and when I try 100 it is out of range).

Comment: I have not given any size to my DataList1 but I have given pagination - 6 items per page. My first item category has five items and for it the code works fine but my second item category has 9 items and show the above error.

Comment: @user1126060 your `DataList1.Items` does have a size.  You're just trying to access an element in it that is out of range (Like the example I have shown you). Try putting a breakpoint on your code and check how many elements `DataList1.Items` has.

Answer (score 0):

`DataList1.Items[item.Id]` can be null, and also `FindControl` can return null, better to use `as` to cast it to a another type. it will not raise exception if not in given type. but you need to check null before use it.

```
if((item.Id < 0) || ((DataList1.Items.Count() -1) < item.Id)) return; // assume item.id is index and integer value 

var dlItem = DataList1.Items[item.Id]; 
if(item !=null){
    rdb1 = dlItem.FindControl("One") as RadioButton;
    rdb2 = dlItem.FindControl("Three") as RadioButton;
    rdb3 = dlItem.FindControl("Seven") as RadioButton;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to access the items by Index rather than IDs.

like

```
RadioButton rdb2 = new RadioButton();
RadioButton rdb3 = new RadioButton();
rdb1 = (RadioButton)DataList1.Items[CurrentIndex].FindControl("One");
rdb2 = (RadioButton)DataList1.Items[CurrentIndex].FindControl("Three");
rdb3 = (RadioButton)DataList1.Items[CurrentIndex].FindControl("Seven");
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused when you have enabled paging in Grid view. If you want to delete a record from grid then you have to do something like this.

int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
 int i = index % 20;
// Here 20 is my GridView's Page Size.
 GridViewRow row = gvMainGrid.Rows[i];
 int id = Convert.ToInt32(gvMainGrid.DataKeys[i].Value);
 new GetData().DeleteRecord(id);
 GridView1.DataSource = RefreshGrid();
 GridView1.DataBind();

Hope this answers the question.